# How do bitcoin exhanges generate the Unique public address for the new user in their exhange?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

I need to know how this bitcoin exhanges generate the unique address    for the new user on their exchanges

Comment: You didn't mention which exchange you are referring to, but I think the answer below is valid for any exchange.

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes the addresses are generally generated using a cryptographically secure random number generator.

Some exchanges may resort to a BIP32-style private key derivation in which private keys for user accounts are generated from a single secret, using hardened derivation for each user's key group. But from outside these are indistinguishable from randomly generated private keys, let alone the public keys.